# Type of variable declared with decltype (having function as an expression)

Tags: c++, decltype

I'm now reading C++ Primer by Stephen Prata and while I read about decltype I'm a little bit confused. In the first part of the paragraph he wrote:

> If expression is a function call, then var has the type of the
>   function return type

and then gives an example

```
long indeed(int);
decltype (indeed(3)) m; // m is type int
```

Isn't that a mistake? My logic says that return type of `indeed` function is `long` and `m` should has type `long`. If I'm right, where is mistake in the first part of paragraph or in the second (example)?

Comment: Note: Stephen Prata wrote C++ Primer Plus, not C++ Primer. The two are easy to confuse and last time I heard, were kind of on different ends of the quality scale. That might have changed by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely the example that is in error. `m` will have type `long`.

Answer (score 0):

It, indeed, is a mistake.

In the given example, `m` will be type `long`.